# Counting specified columns in Group with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, count

I got the following query, which performs well, except that it always has ResubCount = 1, instead of the value for each UserId.

Now:

```
ResolvedDate: Date

ResubCount = 1

UserId = UserId
```

The query now returns (let's say) ten Results from the database.

I want it to be like that:

```
ResolvedDate: Date

ResubCount = 10

UserId = UserId
```

This is my query:

```
var result = (from a in _dataContext.Activities
                          where a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedDate != null
                          group a by new { a.ResolvedDate, a.UserId }
                              into agroup
                              select new
                                         {
                                             ResolvedDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(agroup.Key.ResolvedDate),
                                             ResubCount = agroup.Count(),
                                             UserId = from item in agroup select new { item.UserId }

                                         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Time part of the DateTime may be affecting the grouping:

```
var result = (from a in _dataContext.Activities
              where a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedDate != null
              group a by new 
              { 
                  ResolvedDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.ResolvedDate), 
                  UserId = a.UserId 
              } into agroup
              select new
              {
                  ResolvedDate = agroup.Key.ResolvedDate,
                  ResubCount = agroup.Count(),
                  UserId = agroup.Key.UserId
              });
```

---

Edit: I had `a.ResolvedDate.Date`, however, I don't believe that is supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this gives a compile error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access. - And you're right, .Date is not supported as it's a nullable datetime and LINQ2SQL

Comment: Wouldn't it be the case of calling the `.Value` property of your nullable DateTime?

Comment: This results in a compile error: 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'ResolvedDate' and no extension method 'ResolvedDate' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)